# Get a symbol's value by its name in a sub

Tags: scope, raku, string-interpolation, symbol-table

I'm making a package, where I have to get a symbol's value by its name in a sub, while the symbol is defined outside the sub.

Here is the simplified code, it works as expected：

```
#! /usr/bin/env perl6 

sub dump_value($symbol) {
    say ::("$symbol")
}

# usage:
my $x = 10;
dump_value('$x');

# expected output: 10
# actual output: 10
```

Then I put the 'dump_value' in a standalone file as below:

```
# somelib.pm6
unit module somelib;

sub dump_value($symbol) is export {
    say ::("$symbol")
}
```

```
# client.pl6
#! /usr/bin/env perl6

use lib ".";
use somelib;

my $x = 10;

dump_value('$x');
```

The compiler complained:

```
No such symbol '$x'
  in sub dump_value at xxx/somelib.pm6 (somelib) line 3
  in block <unit> at ./client.pl6 line 8
```

Following are some experiments. None of them succeeded.

```
say ::("MY::$symbol")

say ::("OUR::$symbol")

say ::("OUTER::$symbol")

say ::("CLIENT::$symbol")
...
```

So how to fix the code?

UPDATE:

Thank you! `CALLERS::($symbol)` solved my original problem. But in a bit more complex situation, the complier complained again:

```
# somelib.pm6
unit module somelib;

sub dump_value(@symbols) is export {
    # output: 6
    say CALLERS::('$x');

    # error: No such symbol 'CALLERS::$x'    
    say @symbols.map({ CALLERS::($^id) } ) 
}
```

```
# client.pl6
#! /usr/bin/env perl6

use lib ".";
use somelib;

my $x = 6;
my $y = 8;

dump_value(<$x $y>);
```

UPDATE AGAIN:

use `OUTER::CALLERS::($^id)`.

UPDATE AGAIN AND AGAIN:

After I put the 'dump_value' in another sub, it didn't work any more!

```
# somelib.pm6
unit module somelib;

sub dump_value(@symbols) is export {
    say @symbols.map({ OUTER::CALLERS::($^id) } )
}

sub wrapped_dump_value(@symbols) is export {
    dump_value(@symbols)
}
```

```
#! /usr/bin/env perl6

use lib ".";
use somelib;

my $x = 6;
my $y = 8;

# ouput: (6 8)
dump_value(<$x $y>);

# error: No such symbol 'OUTER::CALLERS::$x'
wrapped_dump_value(<$x $y>);
```

Comment: The following works for me: `say CALLER::MY::($symbol)`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

According to [the documentation](https://docs.perl6.org/language/packages):

> An initial :: doesn't imply global. Here as part of the interpolation
>   syntax it doesn't even imply package. After the interpolation of the
>   ::() component, the indirect name is looked up exactly as if it had
>   been there in the original source code, with priority given first to
>   leading pseudo-package names, then to names in the lexical scope
>   (searching scopes outwards, ending at CORE).

So when you write `say ::("$symbol")` in `dump_value()` in the `somelib` package, it will first lookup `$symbol` in the current scope, which has value `'$x'` then try to look up `$x` (also in the current scope), but the variable `$x` is defined in the caller's lexical scope, so you get the `No such symbol '$x'` error.

You can refer to the caller's lexical symbol given by the value of `$symbol` using either:

```
CALLER::MY::($symbol);  # lexical symbols from the immediate caller's lexical scope
```

or

```
 CALLERS::($symbol); # Dynamic symbols in any caller's lexical scope
```

see [the package documentation page](https://docs.perl6.org/language/packages).

Comment: I am sorry to bother you again, but please see the update at the bottom.

Comment: No problem! Try `OUTER::CALLERS::CALLERS::($^id)`

Comment: The [doc](https://docs.perl6.org/language/packages#Interpolating_into_names) said: `CALLERS` means `Dynamic symbols in **any** caller's lexical scope`. So why does  it need two CALLERS?  I have thought one was enough.

Comment: I am not sure, maybe a bug or something that I missed. Maybe some of the experts here can answer this? I agree that this is unclear and I will look into it also..

Answer (score 0):

Couple of things:

```
use lib ".";
use somelib;
our $x = 10;     # You need to export the value into the global scope
dump_value('$x');
```

Then, use the [global scope](https://docs.perl6.org/language/packages#index-entry-OUTER_%28package%29):

```
unit module somelib;

sub dump_value($symbol) is export {
    say GLOBAL::("$symbol")
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Asking users to use 'our'  is a bit annoying.

Comment: @lovetomato well, it signals it might be used in other lexical scope, which is what it's done now.

Comment: I am sorry to  bother you again, but please see the update at the bottom.